# *67 in phone number for IOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, openurl

I know it is possible to dial an extension after you have dialed a phone number from an app but I am not finding a way to add *67 or call blocking in front of a phone number for my IOS app.  I have tried different variations of this but nothing has worked.  Does anyone know if this is possible or does Apple not support such a feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

You cannot make the iPhone dial a `*` or a `#` using a `tel` URL.  Apple documents its support for `tel` URLs in the [*Apple URL Scheme Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html), which says this:

> Specifically, if a URL contains the `*` or `#` characters, the Phone app does not attempt to dial the corresponding phone number.

Comment: THank you for you response.  I was hoping that was not the case and there was a way around it.  I have already submitted a feature request to Apple based on this.

Comment: probably they will not support your request as it would be possible to send codes so for the security reasons they won't add it I guess